# Android Room Query cannot use same variable more than once

Tags: android-room

I am trying to convert this raw query to Query.

Raw Query:

```
SELECT * from numbers WHERE number=$numberToSearch OR number LIKE '%$numberToSearch%' OR number LIKE '%$numberToSearch' OR number LIKE '$numberToSearch%'
```

I started with simple one and created this Query

```
 @Query("SELECT * from numbers WHERE number=:numberToSearch OR number LIKE :numberToSearch")
```

However, room things that my query needs to variables and creates exception. I can of course provide :numberToSearch few times as variable but that doe not sound right.

Is there any way writing a Query that works?

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose your like query with `%` before passing as a parameter.

So correct representation of what you original query is goes as follows

```
val numberToSearch = 123
val numberToSearchLike = `%$numberToSearch%`
// You have to call with two parameters as parameters are not same
searchNumber(numberToSearch, numberToSearchLike)
```

And your *DAO* should look like this

```
@Query("SELECT * from numbers WHERE number=:numberToSearch OR number LIKE :numberToSearchLike")
fun searchNumber(numberToSearch:Int, numberToSearchLike: String)
```

Thats actually the way your do `LIKE` operations in Room

#### P.S.

In fact you don't have to have `WHERE number=:numberToSearch` as your `LIKE` operator will return the same thing. 
So your query is same as saying

```
@Query("SELECT * from numbers WHERE number LIKE :numberToSearchLike")
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about "%$numberToSearch%" but wanted to find out if there is a way to re-use the same variable